# Weird (py)serial linux corruption

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, pyserial

I have a Linux SBC based on the Atmel SAMA5D36. I have another device hooked up to it via /dev/ttyS2 via TTL lines (115200 8N1). Using pyserial, I have a pretty high bandwidth query/response conversation with that device.

Periodically (at least once a minute), I see a very repeatable corruption of the date coming back from the other device. If it were to respond with some text like

```
"123456" (ascii character values)
```

It will drop one character AND add character-0 after the following character:

```
"13\x00456"
```

Hopefully that's clear. It will drop the 2, the next character is as expected, a character-0 follows, and then back to normal.

I am using kernel 4.1.10. Via some debug statements, I'm pretty sure this is not happening in my python loop, because the 0's show up in random spots of the read() buffer. I have also hooked up a scope on the incoming lines and have verified that the wire is not carrying this corruption.

I am looking for an answer that can get me in the right direction of figuring out why this is happening. CPU load does *seem* to increase the frequency (for example, when I'm doing a bunch of DBUS traffic for a BLE adaptor attached).

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty high bandwidth"? You say you have "verified that the wire is not carrying this corruption" - that's actually rather difficult to do with an analog scope if this error is only happening once/minute and there is a lot of data flowing. One possibility is that your SBC uart is overrunning the serial Rx perhaps because other higher-priority interrupts are blocking the uart for >80us-ish which is a character time at 115200 baud. Or if the uart has e.g. A 16-byte rx fifo, and interrupts are blocked for >1ms-ish although that sounds unlikely.

Comment: I'll instrument it tomorrow when I'm at the machine to get a more numerical answer on high bandwidth.

Comment: I verified the lack of corruption on the wire (right were it plugs into the pins on the Linux SBC) using a PicoScope that can do serial decoding of the stream. By getting my software to drive a gpio pin when I detect an unexpected zero, I can trigger the scope on that and then compare character for character what went in, and what came out on the pyserial side.

Comment: Is there  way I can figure out how big the rx fifos are? Does the Linux DTS expose that? Or do I need to go data sheet diving to figure that out. Are there any low level linux tools where I could tap the serial port receive and help figure out where the corruption is entering at?

Comment: Has fifos: look at the datasheet. Low-level linux tools: sorry, don't know. If the uart has fifos it would be surprising if the driver didn't enable them - but yes worth checking it does actually enable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a result of overflow errors.  If you look at atmel_serial you can see if there are any errors.

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/atmel_serial
```

For example on ttyS2 you might see something like this (oe: shows the overflow errors):

```
2: uart:ATMEL_SERIAL mmio:0xF0020000 irq:31 tx:266758 rx:361385 oe:51 RTS|DTR|DSR|CD|RI
```

Since you are high rate serial you might try implementing DMA on the USART lines.  Tweak the appropriate dts file in your kernel by adding the following to your usart settings:

```
atmel,use-dma-rx;
atmel,use-dma-tx;
```

For my kernel, I had to disable SPI and I2C so that there would be enough DMA channels available for the USART.

Comment: That got me there! Thanks! Moved up to a newer kernel as well.